# Why does grepl in R delete every second row (although this is not specified)

Tags: r, grepl

I want to prepare multiple dataframes for analyses in R.
Some of them do contain variable labels (= strings) in the first row (type 1), some don't (type 2). Please note that I don't mean a header with the first row.
All other rows contain numeric values.

My input data frames:
Type 1:

x-axis y-axis

```
0     200  
5     299
4     314
17    117
```

Type 2:

```
0     200  
5     299
4     314
17    117
```

In the end, I want to have all data frames without those strings in the first row.
Intended output for both types:

```
0     200  
5     299
4     314
17    117
```

Because I don't want to manually check which of the data frames contain the strings, I would love to run a code across all data frames that deletes the "string row".

I noticed that some codes delete all data from data frames that don't contain the string.
So, I now use the following code that should prevent this issue:

df_new <- df[!grepl("x-axis", df) , ]

For the data frames without those strings, this is working perfectly (= nothing happens).
However, for data frames that include those strings, R does not only delete this row (great), but also every second row.

Anyone there who knows a solution?

Comment: Please include a simple example of the data you are working with, along with the expected output.

Comment: You don't want the whole df as the second argument to `grepl`. Try `df_new <- df[!grepl("x-axis", df[1,]) , ]`

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion! Unfortunately, still every second row is deleted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As commented by @AndrewGustar, you should pass the column to grepl, not the entire data.frame.  But a little more explanation may also help here.

The second argument to `grepl` should normally be a character vector. But if it is not, then R will attempt to coerce it into one using `as.character`.  Lets make a dummy example to see how this works:

```
df = data.frame(V1=c('x', rep('foo',9)), V2 = 1:10, stringsAsFactors = F)
    # V1 V2
# 1    x  1
# 2  foo  2
# 3  foo  3
# 4  foo  4
# 5  foo  5
# 6  foo  6
# 7  foo  7
# 8  foo  8
# 9  foo  9
# 10 foo 10
```

Now, if we do `as.character(df)`, we get

```
[1] "c(\"x\", \"foo\", \"foo\", \"foo\", \"foo\", 
       \"foo\", \"foo\", \"foo\", \"foo\", \"foo\")"
[2] "1:10"
```

`grepl` acting on this will find the search string 'x' in the first of these elements, but no the second:

```
grepl("x", df)
# [1]  TRUE FALSE
```

This gets recycled in `df[!grepl("x", df) , ]` to return every second row

```
df_new
#    V1 V2
#2  foo  2
#4  foo  4
#6  foo  6
#8  foo  8
#10 foo 10
```

So the solution is to just grepl the column you want:

```
df_new <- df[!grepl("x", df$V1) , ]
```

#### Note

An interesting, and maybe unintuitive side-effect of the fact that `as.character` returns the 2nd column as `1:10`, is that `grepl("1", df)` gives `[1] FALSE  TRUE` (as expected). But, `grepl("4", df)` returns `[1] FALSE FALSE` even though 4 does appear in the second column.

Comment: Thank you, this is working fine! However, if I want to apply the code via lapply to a list of all files, I get an error that !grepl(....) isn't a function. Is there anything I do wrong here?                             `list_new <- lapply(list, !grepl("x-axis", list$V1), )`

Comment: something like `lapply(list, function(x) !grepl("x-axis", x$V1))`. This is really a separate question, and you should have a look at more general examples of how to use `apply` type loops.

Answer (score 0):

If you call `grepl` on a data.frame, it will return results by column, not by cell.

```
df <- data.frame('a' = c('th', 'the', 'tre', 'test'),
                 'b' = c('cat', 'cart', 'ca', 'fat'),
                 'c' = c('re', 'awe', 'io', 'ko'),
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

grepl('cat', df)
[1] FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```

If you're interested in searching just one column, use @AndrewGustar's solution and just pass that column into grepl:

```
grepl('cat', df$b)
```

If you want to get rows that have the value anywhere, apply by row with `apply`:

```
apply(df, 1, function(x) sum(grepl('cat', x)))
```

or to drop those rows which contain that value:

```
df[!apply(df, 1, function(x) sum(grepl('cat', x))),]
```